# How can I display selected variant images on Shopify only?

Tags: shopify, variant

In the thumbnail, all the images are shown which confuses the customer. How to make sure only selected variant images are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify 2.0 templates come with this feature as a built-in option. You can refer to the screenshot below for clarification.

[image]

If you don't find this feature available in your template, it might require code customization to implement it effectively.